# Reformat existing table from paired columns into rows

Tags: sql-server, unpivot

For example I have a table with 5 rows and 7 columns, I wish to move the last two columns into the previous two columns. New format of table would now be 10 rows and 5 columns

Present Table format

```
+-----+------------+----------+------------+---------------+------------+---------------+
| id  | VisitDate  | fkFamily | child1.DOB | child1.Gender | child2.DOB | child2.Gender |
+-----+------------+----------+------------+---------------+------------+---------------+
|  78 | 19/04/2010 |      277 | 14/03/2009 | 0             | NULL       | NULL          |
|  79 | 20/04/2010 |      289 | 12/08/2007 | 0             | NULL       | NULL          |
| 107 | 20/04/2010 |      191 | NULL       | NULL          | NULL       | NULL          |
| 108 | 20/04/2010 |      259 | NULL       | NULL          | 31/03/2010 | 1             |
| 109 | 20/04/2010 |      126 | NULL       | NULL          | NULL       | NULL          |
+-----+------------+----------+------------+---------------+------------+---------------+
```

New table format

```
+-----+------------+----------+------------+----------------------+
| id  | VisitDate  | fkFamily | child.DOB  | child.Gender         |
+-----+------------+----------+------------+----------------------+
|  78 | 19/04/2010 |      277 | 14/03/2009 | 0                    |
|  79 | 20/04/2010 |      289 | 12/08/2007 | 0                    |
| 107 | 20/04/2010 |      191 | NULL       | NULL                 |
| 108 | 20/04/2010 |      259 | NULL       | NULL                 |
| 109 | 20/04/2010 |      126 | NULL       | NULL                 |
|  78 | 19/04/2010 |      277 | NULL       | NULL                 |
|  79 | 20/04/2010 |      289 | NULL       | NULL                 |
| 107 | 20/04/2010 |      191 | NULL       | NULL                 |
| 108 | 20/04/2010 |      259 | 31/03/2010 | 1                    |
| 109 | 20/04/2010 |      126 | NULL       | NULL                 |
+-----+------------+----------+------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: ddl and sample would make this not only legible, but also make it possible to help. It is impossible to decipher this as posted. sqlfiddle.com is a great place to start.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the final result by unpivoting the columns `Child1_DOB`, `Child1_Gender`, etc.  Starting in SQL Server 2005, the unpivot function was made available but for your case I'd actually use `CROSS APPLY` so you can unpivot the `Child1`, and `Child2` values in pairs.

The syntax would be:

```
select 
  t.id,
  t.visitdate,
  t.fkFamily,
  c.child_DOB,
  c.child_Gender
from yourtable t
cross apply
(
  select child1_DOB, child1_Gender union all
  select child2_DOB, child2_Gender
) c (child_DOB, child_Gender);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/28a4f/1)

Then you could also include an identifier for each of the values so you know if it belonged to child one or two:

```
select 
  t.id,
  t.visitdate,
  t.fkFamily,
  c.child,
  c.child_DOB,
  c.child_Gender
from yourtable t
cross apply
(
  select 'Child1', child1_DOB, child1_Gender union all
  select 'Child2', child2_DOB, child2_Gender
) c (child, child_DOB, child_Gender)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/28a4f/5). These give a result similar to:

```
|  ID |  VISITDATE | FKFAMILY |  CHILD_DOB | CHILD_GENDER |
|-----|------------|----------|------------|--------------|
|  78 | 19/04/2010 |      277 | 14/03/2009 |            0 |
|  78 | 19/04/2010 |      277 |     (null) |       (null) |
|  79 | 20/04/2010 |      289 | 12/08/2007 |            0 |
|  79 | 20/04/2010 |      289 |     (null) |       (null) |
| 107 | 20/04/2010 |      191 |     (null) |       (null) |
| 107 | 20/04/2010 |      191 |     (null) |       (null) |
| 108 | 20/04/2010 |      259 |     (null) |       (null) |
| 108 | 20/04/2010 |      259 | 31/03/2010 |            1 |
| 109 | 20/04/2010 |      126 |     (null) |       (null) |
| 109 | 20/04/2010 |      126 |     (null) |       (null) |
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reformat the table into something like this by using UNION:-

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT id, VisitDate, fkFamily, child1_DOB as child_DOB, child1_Gender as child_Gender
FROM yourtable
UNION
SELECT id, VisitDate, fkFamily, child2_DOB, child2_Gender
FROM yourtable) as temp
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/28a4f/4)

You could use SELECT INTO if you wanted to create a new table from the results, for example:-

```
SELECT * INTO yournewtable FROM (
    SELECT id, VisitDate, fkFamily, child1_DOB as child_DOB, child1_Gender as child_Gender
    FROM yourtable
    UNION
    SELECT id, VisitDate, fkFamily, child2_DOB, child2_Gender
    FROM yourtable) as temp
```